# Endless page loads same records over and over again

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm using Rails and Kaminari and am trying to implement endless scrolling on comments below Locations and Posts. I got the beginnging right but when I scroll down, it loads the same comments over and over again. How to make it so that it loads comments properly?

here is my **locations/show.js.erb**

```
  1 $('#comments').append('<%= j render(@comments) %>');
```

here's my **comments.js**

```
  5 jQuery ->
  6   $(window).scroll ->  
  7     if $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 200
  8       $.getScript($('.pagination .next_page a').attr('href'))
```

my **comments controller** show action

```
 18   def show
 19     @title = @location.name
 20     @comments = @location.comments.order("created_at desc").page(params[:page]).per(35)
 21     @commentable = @location
 22     @comment = @location.comments.build
 23     respond_to do |format|
 24       format.html
 25       format.js
 26     end
 27   end
```

EDIT: this is the pagination html source

```
<div class="pagination">
    <ul>

          <li class="active">
  <a href="#">1</a>
</li>

          <li class="">
  <a href="/locations/1?page=2" rel="next">2</a>
</li>

          <li class="">
  <a href="/locations/1?page=3">3</a>
</li>

          <li class="">
  <a href="/locations/1?page=4">4</a>
</li>

          <li class="">
  <a href="/locations/1?page=5">5</a>
</li>

      <li>
  <a href="/locations/1?page=5">Last &raquo;</a>
</li>

    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: what's in the script you retrive? What changes value of pagination `next`? Too many unknowns

Comment: are you sure that `page(params[:page])` is working as expected?

Comment: I also think this next_page thing is causing the problem. It isn't changing I think. When I manually pass in the params in url, it changes as it should though...
@charlietfl what code more do you need, and Ill add it.

Comment: show source html of `next` link so can see `href`. Will need to modify it when script loads.

Comment: added the html source of next link. How to modify it in the script?

Comment: can easily modify the href but your pagination won't reflect updates without doing a redraw, is that acceptable? If not use integrated solution provided by @enviable

Comment: by redraw you mean reload? if not than it is acceptable :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found what the problem was. Thanks to the guys who helped, much appreciated. **Here's the code that worked.** ( sorry if the comments bother you but I decided to leave them here in case someone wants to correct me or in case they help someone in the future ).

**locations.js.coffee**

```
  5 # Infinite scroll
  6 jQuery ->
  7   # it doesn't listen for the scroll unless there is location_comments class
  8   if $('.location_comments').length
  9     $(window).scroll ->
 10       # finds anchor tag in pagination with rel attribute = 'next'
 11       $next = $(".pagination a[rel='next']")
 12       # sets url variable to the href value of that anchor tag
 13       url = $($next).attr('href')
 14       if url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 200
 15         # since this replaces whole pagination with this text, it prevents loading of too many records.
 16         # This line ise immediatly followed by this getScript() wich triggers another operation on .pagination
 17         $('.pagination').text 'Fetching more comments...'
 18         # triggers /locations/show.js.erb
 19         $.getScript(url)
 20     $(window).scroll
```

**locations/show.js.erb**

```
  1 $('.location_comments').append('<%= j render @comments %>');
  2 $('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j paginate @comments %>');
  3 /* Add code for removing pagination if the user is on last page */
```

**comments controller**

```
  9   def create
 10     @comment = @commentable.comments.build(params[:comment])
 11     @comment.user = current_user
 12 
 13     respond_to do |format|
 14       if @comment.save
 15         format.html { redirect_to @commentable, :notice => 'Comment created' }
 16         format.js
 17       else
 18         format.html { redirect_to @commentable, :alert => 'Comment not created' }
 19         format.js
 20       end
 21     end
```

**locations controller**

```
 18   def show
 19     @title = @location.name
 20     @comments = @location.comments.order("created_at desc").page(params[:page]).per(35)
 21     @commentable = @location
 22     @comment = @location.comments.build
 23   end
```

**I still have to find out how to hide .pagination when the user is on last page,** so if anyone wants to help with that that'd be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

The .next_page link isn't changing.
The link is just whatever.com/?page=2. When you're scrolling, it's just making a request for the same page. You'll either need your javascript to update the page number in the link, or not reference the DOM like that.

You can update the paginator with:

```
$('.pagination').html('<%= escape_javascript(paginate(@comments)) %>');
```

Kaminari has a 'How To' for this: [How-To:-Create-Infinite-Scrolling-with-jQuery](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/wiki/How-To%3a-Create-Infinite-Scrolling-with-jQuery)

Comment: I know of this but would like to do it without extra dependency ( sausage )

Comment: The important part of that 'how to' is the page++. You need to iterate the page number somewhere. Unless you need the button for the user to interact with, it'd be best done in code.

Comment: aaah! can you show me how to ++ the page with JS? And not to change code too much?

Answer (score 1):

Within callback of `$.getScript` you can increment page number of `next` with:

```
jQuery ->
    $(window).scroll ->  
      if $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 200
        var $next=$('.pagination .next_page a')
         $.getScript($next.attr('href'), function(){
              /* script has loaded*/
              $next.attr('href', function(i, currHref){
                 return currHref.replace(/(?!page\=)(\d)/, function(match){
                        return parseInt(match,10)+1;
                   });
              });
         });
```

Comment: ok, I've converted it all to normal JS here > https://gist.github.com/ofcan/4967739 < but still it does the same thing?

Comment: you added `return` in places it doesn't belong

Comment: basic code I provided works, not sure what is happening in you implementation  http://jsfiddle.net/8MF9x/

Comment: perhaps script you load does something to pager?